# Incorrect Syntax near "@PasswordHash"

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

Ok, I've checked a number of different similar issues, but nothing of the similar cases seems to solve my problem, or I'm missing something.

Relevant method:

```
private void ApplyPasswordToUser(string username, string passwordHash)
{
        using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand 
            {
                Connection = connection,
                CommandText = "dbo.AddPasswordHash @Username @PasswordHash"
            };

            command.Parameters.Add("@Username",SqlDbType.NVarChar,24).Value = username;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PasswordHash",passwordHash);

            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Error here
        }
}
```

dbo.AddPasswordHash:

```
    @Username nchar(24),
    @PasswordHash nchar(80)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE dbo.UserPass
    SET Password_Hash = @PasswordHash
    WHERE Username = @Username
END
```

I'm using the Blowfish algorithm from the CryptSharp NuGet Package.

I have 3 other commands that don't pass that password hash as input and all work perfectly fine. This one seems to have issued no matter what I seem to change.

The hash contains various special characters in its string, so I'm not sure if that is affecting whether or not the command gets through.

Comment: Did you try to use the standard way to call a stored procedure? IE, without passing parameters and setting CommandType to StoredProcedure

Comment: The stored procedure defines the `@Username` as `nchar(24)` - but your C# code claims it's `nvarchar(24)` - those definitions **must match* ... and why aren't you defining the parameter type for `@passwordHash` ?? WHy use the `AddWithValue` which is known to have its share of problems.....

Comment: @marc_s I didn't know AddWithValue causes problems... though did originally use Add but changed the code to see if the error persisted, which it did.

Comment: @Steve Will try the standard way.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest using code like this:

```
    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("dbo.AddPasswordHash", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        command.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NChar, 24).Value = username;
        command.Parameters.Add("@PasswordHash", SqlDbType.NChar, 80).Value = passwordHash);

        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

- Use the proper syntax for calling a stored procedure
- Use the proper syntax for defining parameters (with defining their proper types)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Sorry, a little new to SQL and this kind of does complicate me.

Comment: @MadManiac: that's okay - we all live and learn every single day. That's what SO is great for to grow your knowledge and improve your skills